Compilation Error: Expected Statement - Autofilter VBA Excel
I am trying to run a VBA script on power automate.
I want to filter a column and I have ran the following code
set app=createobject("Excel.Application")
app.visible=True
set Wbook=app.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\AJ20519854\Downloads\OneDrive_1_27-5-2024\14th May 2024_2024-05-14_15-35-41.320.csv")
set Wsheet=Wbook.Worksheets("14th May 2024_2024-05-14_15-35-")
Wsheet.Rows("1:12").Delete
Wsheet.Columns("A").Delete

Wsheet.Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter
Wsheet.Range("$A$1:$M$4932").AutoFilter Field:="11", Criteria1:="APEXONE_OSCE"

After running on power automate it shows compliation error: Expected Statement
What did I do wrong?

Which line in the code you have posted gives the error?

Looks like your filename is 14th May 2024_2024-05-14_15-35-41.320.csv but your sheet name is 14th May 2024_2024-05-14_15-35- (so they do not match.) - try changing it to use an index instead to avoid having to use the name - set Wsheet=Wbook.Worksheets(1)

"After running on power automate" - please add a little more detail around what exactly that looks like.
